# using xrange output not expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, xrange

```
s = 0

for s in xrange(0, 100):
    print "s before", s
    if s % 10 == 0:
        s += 10
    print "s after", s
```

[image: result of loop1]

```
s = 0

while s < 100:
    print "s before", s
    if s % 10 == 0:
        s += 10
    s += 1
    print "s after", s
```

[image: result of loop2]

As pictures shown above, why those 2 loops doing similar things, one using xrange while another using while-loop are giving me exact different output?

Comment: These are different loops!

Comment: Because `for` sets `s` from the iterable, and setting `s` to something else in the loop doesn't change the iterable.

Comment: You are essentially asking why `s = first_thing` then `s = second_thing` didn't change `first_thing`.

Comment: yes, thank you very much.GOT IT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` in the first loop is overwritten by the values coming from `xrange(0, 100)` whereas in the second loop you are *manually* initializing the variable `s=0` and then incrementing it with `s += 10`. So, it's exactly the expected behavior.

You need to have a look into variable scopes in python. Check this discussion: [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: Thank you very much for ur answer and ur link shared.

Comment: Thanks very much and sorry for the late reply. And most importantly, you solved my problem.